# how to prevent more clicking in jquery slider

Tags: jquery

i want to make a jquery slider , everything works fine but when i click once more quickly it's sliding once more.I want that after finishing one sliding then next clicking will fire.How can i do that?

here is the live slider, have a look.
https://nur-alam.github.io/jQuerySlider/

here is my jquery code.

```
 (function($){


    var _gallery = $('#slider');
    _gallery.find('ul').attr('class','slides');
    _gallery.find('ul>li').attr('class','slide');
    var _slides = _gallery.find('.slides');
    var _slide = _gallery.find('.slide');


    _gallery.find('li:first').clone(true).appendTo(_gallery.find('ul'));
    _gallery.find('ul>li:first').addClass('active');

    totalSlides = _gallery.find('li').length;
    mainDivWidth = _gallery.outerWidth(true);
    eachSlideWidth = _gallery.find('li').outerWidth(true);
    totalWidth = totalSlides*eachSlideWidth;


    _gallery.find('ul').css('width',totalWidth);
    _gallery.find('ul>li').css('width',mainDivWidth);


    /*previous sliding function*/
    $('.prev_area').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        /*getting the index of active li element*/
        index = _gallery.find('.active').index();

        active = _gallery.find('.active');
        activeNext = active.prev();
        console.log(active);
        console.log(activeNext);

        /*if active li element is first li then go to last slide*/
        if(index == 0){
            activeNext = _gallery.find('ul>li').eq(totalSlides-2);
            activeNext.addClass('active');
            firstActive = _gallery.find('.active').eq(0);
            firstActive.removeClass('active');
            _slides.css('margin-left',-(totalWidth-eachSlideWidth));
            _slides.animate({'margin-left':'+='+mainDivWidth},750,'swing');
        }else{
            activeNext.addClass('active');
            active.removeClass('active');
            _slides.animate({'margin-left':'+='+mainDivWidth},750,'swing'); 
        }

    }); 



    /* next sliding function*/
    function nextSlideing(){

        /* getting the index of active li element*/
        index = _gallery.find('.active').index();

        active = _gallery.find('.active');
        activeNext = active.next();
        activeNext.addClass('active');
        firstActive = _gallery.find('.active').eq(0);
        firstActive.removeClass('active');

        _slides.animate({'margin-left':'-='+mainDivWidth},750,'swing',function(){
            /*if active index is last li element then add active class to first li element*/
            if(index===(totalSlides-2)){
                _gallery.find('ul>li').removeClass('active');
                _gallery.find('ul>li:first').addClass('active');
                _slides.css('margin-left',0);
            }
        });

    }


    /* next cliking event*/
    $(document).on('click','.next_area',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        nextSlideing();
    }); 

}(jQuery))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're making a carousel. There are some really good carousels out there but that's not what you asked for. You probably want to avoid sliding when you're already in an animation.

-Edit-

Based on what I think you're saying in your comments and reconsidering your code, isSliding needs to be reset in the complete callback of your animate() call instead of the end of the nextSlideing [sic] function. You'll need to do something similar in your previous slide version as well.

```
var isSliding = false;
/* next sliding function*/
function nextSlideing(){
  if (!isSliding) {
    isSliding = true;
    /* getting the index of active li element*/
    index = _gallery.find('.active').index();

    active = _gallery.find('.active');
    activeNext = active.next();
    activeNext.addClass('active');
    firstActive = _gallery.find('.active').eq(0);
    firstActive.removeClass('active');

    _slides.animate({'margin-left':'-='+mainDivWidth},750,'swing',function(){
        /*if active index is last li element then add active class to first li element*/
        if(index===(totalSlides-2)){
            _gallery.find('ul>li').removeClass('active');
            _gallery.find('ul>li:first').addClass('active');
            _slides.css('margin-left',0);
        }
        isSliding = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you clicking during the slide or are you looking for something to stop clicks for some duration afterwards?

Comment: i want after one sliding then next clicking button will work

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem with unbind mehtod.